# Need to create li with list of different links using php explode method

Tags: php, explode

here is my working php explode code for NON links:

```
<?php
            $textarea = get_custom_field('my_custom_output');
            $array = explode(',',$textarea);
            $output = ''; // initialize the variable
            foreach ($array as $item) {
               $item = trim($item); // clear off white-space
               $output .= '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
            }


?>

            <ul>
            <?php print $output; ?>
            </ul>
```

..and the code which defines "my_custom_output", which I input into my textarea field:

```
text1,text2,text3,etc
```

..and the finished product:

- text1
- text2
- text3
- etc

So that works. 
Now what I want to do is make text1 be a link to mywebsite.com/text1-page-url/

I was able to get this far:

```
<?php
            $textarea = get_custom_field('my_custom_output');
            $array = explode(',',$textarea);
            $output = ''; // initialize the variable
            foreach ($array as $item) {
               $item = trim($item); // clear off white-space
               $output .= '<li class="link-class"><a title="' . $item . '" href="http://mywebsite.com/' . $item_links . '">' . $item . '</a></li>';
            }


?>

            <ul>
            <?php print $output; ?>
            </ul>
```

Now, I would like $item_links to define just the rest of the url. For example:
I want to put input this into my textarea:

```
text1:text1-page-url,text2:new-text2-page,text3:different-page-text3
```

and have the output be this:

- [text1](http://mywebsite.com/text1-page-url)
- [text2](http://mywebsite.com/new-text2-page)
- ..etc (stackoverflow forced me to only have two links in this post because I only have 0 reputation)

another thing I want to do is change commas to new lines. I know the code for a new line is \n but I do not know how to swap it out. That way I can put this:

```
text1:text1-page-url
text2:new-text2-page
text3:different-page-text3
```

I hope I made this easy for you to understand. I am almost there, I am just stuck. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the $item inside your loop with `explode()`:

```
<?php
$separator1 = "\n";
$separator2 = ":";
$textarea = get_custom_field('my_custom_output');
$array = explode($separator1,$textarea);
$output = ''; // initialize the variable
foreach ($array as $item) {
    list($item_text, $item_links) = explode($separator2, trim($item));
    $output .= '<li class="link-class"><a title="' . $item_text . '" href="http://mywebsite.com/' . $item_links . '">' . $item_text . '</a></li>';
}
?>

<ul>
<?php print $output; ?>
</ul>
```

And choose your string separators so `$item_text, $item_links` wouldn't contain them.

Comment: I think this might work!! I will try it. Thanks! Get back to you in a few minutes to let you know if it works.

Comment: Now I need to add a third demiliter. Hope you can help! =D Thanks so much for all your help so far! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598377/need-to-add-second-line-and-third-delimiter-on-php-explode

Answer (score 0):

After you explode the string you could loop through again and separate the text and link into key/values.  Something like...

```
$array_final = new array();
$array_temp = explode(',', $textarea);
foreach($array_temp as $item) {
    list($text, $link) = explode(':', $item);
    $array_final[$text] = $link;
}

foreach($array_final as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$value.'">'.$key.'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: I see two flaws here: 1) we can't guarantee the `$key` is unique, so some data can be lost; 2) there's no need for the second loop, it's waste of resources.

Comment: yeah, i like how you did it in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

to change comma into new line you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like

```
str_replace(",", "\r\n", $output)
```

Comment: i meant i would just manually be entering the new line. there will not ever be any commas

Comment: seems like I misunderstood "another thing I want to do is change commas to new lines" - apologizes

Comment: no problem. i would thumbs up you but unfortunately i have to have 15 rep to do so. thank you for your answer! it helps me learn even though it is not relevant for my current needs.