# Need to add second line and third delimiter on php explode

Tags: php, explode

This is tailing off my other question which was successfully answered: stackoverflow.com/questions/8597929/need-to-create-li-with-list-of-different-links-using-php-explode-method

so now I have this:

```
<?php
$separator1 = "\n";
$separator2 = ":";
$textarea = get_custom_field('my_custom_output');
$array = explode($separator1,$textarea);
$output = ''; // initialize the variable
foreach ($array as $item) {
    list($item_text, $item_links) = explode($separator2, trim($item));
    $output .= '<li class="link-class"><a title="' . $item_text . '" href="http://mywebsite.com/' . $item_links . '">' . $item_text . '</a></li>';
}
?>

<ul>
<?php print $output; ?>
</ul>
```

and that, using the following in a textarea which is defined to "my_custom_output":

```
text1:text1-page-url
text2:new-text2-page
text3:different-page-text3
```

and the result is

```
text1
text2
text3
```

which are successfully linked and styled. (i didnt make them links because stackoverflow doesn't let me post more than two links because i only have 3 rep).

So my next and final desired task is to do this:

```
text1
description 1
text2
description 2
text3
description 3
```

where the text1 etc are linked like before but the descriptions are not linked.

So I will do my best, right here in stackoverflow, to try it. However, I expect I will need some help. Let's go:

```
<?php
$separator1 = "\n";
$separator2 = ":";
$separator3 = ";";
$textarea = get_custom_field('my_custom_output');
$array = explode($separator1,$textarea);
$output = ''; // initialize the variable
foreach ($array as $item) {
    list($item_text, $item_links) = explode($separator2, trim($item));
    $output .= '<li class="link-class"><a title="' . $item_text . '" href="http://mywebsite.com/' . $item_links . '">' . $item_text . '</a><br /><span class="desc-class">' . $item_desc . '</span></li>';
}
?>

<ul>
<?php print $output; ?>
</ul>
```

and to use the following in the textarea which is is defined to "my_custom_output":

```
text1:text1-page-url;Text1 Description
text2:new-text2-page;Description For Text2
text3:different-page-text3;A Text3 Description
```

and I need the output to be:

- [text1](http://mywebsite.com/text1-page-url)

  Text1 Description
- [text2](http://mywebsite.com/new-text2-page)

  Description For Text2
- ..etc

I don't know if semicolon will work, but I can't use a space (\s) because there are spaces in the description. I am open to suggestions.

====================================================

MY NEWEST TRY:

```
<?php
$separator1 = "\n";
$separator2 = ":";
$separator3 = ";";
$textarea = get_custom_field('my_custom_output');
$array = explode($separator1,$textarea);
$output = ''; // initialize the variable
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $itemarray = explode($separator2, trim($item));
    $item_text = $itemarray[0];
    list($item_links, $item_desc) = explode($separator3,$itemarray[1]);

    $output .= '<li class="link-class"><a title="' . $item_text . '" href="http://mywebsite.com/' . $item_links . '">' . $item_text . '</a><br /><span class="desc-class">' . $item_desc . '</span></li>';
}
?>

<ul>
<?php print $output; ?>
</ul>
```

IT WORKS!!! =D

Comment: Would using commas work (following typical CSV)?

Comment: I think so. Thanks for the suggestion! semicolon looks like it might work also though. =) Probably good if I ever wanted to add a fourth delimiter 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand this well enough (I'm not sure what get_custom_field() gets you - can't find that as a regular PHP function), but when you explode an item that has multiple instances of the delimiter, you'll get multiple arrays.

So:

```
$textarea = "text1:text1-page-url;Text1 Description";
$data = explode(':',$textarea);
// at this point $data[0] will contain "text1", while $data[1] contains text1-page-url;Text1 Description"
$descarray = explode(';',$data[1]);
// then $descarray[0] contains "text1-page-url" and $descarray[1] contains "Text1 Description" so you can echo this out however you like.
```

To work with your code..
Assume each $item is each row at this point, like this:

```
$item = "text1:text1-page-url;Text1 Description";
```

Then this will do the trick:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $itemarray = explode($separator2, trim($item));
    $item_text = $itemarray[0];
    list($item_links, $item_desc) = explode(';',$itemarray[1]);

    $output .= '<li class="link-class"><a title="' . $item_text . '" href="http://mywebsite.com/' . $item_links . '">' . $item_text . '</a><br /><span class="desc-class">' . $item_desc . '</span></li>';
}
```

Comment: get_custom_field() is simply the call for a custom field for Wordpress that allows me to pull the data for my_custom_output ("my_custom_output" is just a name I made up for my custom code I use to input data. you could name it anything. like mr_smith_0001. it is a variable. On the other hand, get_custom_field() is a constant)

Comment: can we stick to my current method so i can learn better? thanks. I don't really understand yours answer.

Comment: or if this would work, please show me how to use this with what I already have. thank you.

Comment: I am kind of understanding this now, but not sure how to integrate it with my current code.

Comment: I added new code. check the answer again. Also note that you can just do a multiple array split. If your original string has ; as delimiters all along without the ":" in there, you'd get $itemarray[0] as the title, $itemarray[1] as the link, $itemarray[2] as the description.

Comment: ok refreshed this page. looking at your new code now. i had tried it, I might need to revise.

Comment: ok i am pasting my try using your help up in the question. please take a look. I think I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: You need to add $array = explode($separator1,$textarea); to create an $array out of your get_custom_field() function results. Your current function turns in a totally empty $array var.

Comment: thank you i just came back to add it in, i also noticed it! I am learning... thanks to you helpful people!!

Comment: im going to try the code on my site now. be back in a few minutes!

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!! =D =D =D YAY!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU ALLL!!!
AND MERRRY CHRISTMAS!!!

Comment: Awesome glad I could help. PHP is a lot of fun. I was learning the same stuff years ago, and I had lots of good samaritans help me. Pay it forward when you become the next big expert! Merry Xmas.

Answer (score 0):

I'd slightly optimize the algorithm as there is no need for second `explode()`. Just separate substrings within one row with the same separators (and don't forget to escape that separator inside all your data):

```
<?php
$row_separator = "\n";
$line_separator = ":";
$textarea = get_custom_field('my_custom_output');
$array = explode($row_separator, $textarea);
$output = ''; // initialize the variable
foreach ($array as $item) {
    list($item_text, $item_links, $item_desc) = explode($line_separator, trim($item));
    $output .= '<li class="link-class"><a title="' . $item_text . '" href="http://mywebsite.com/' . $item_links . '">' . $item_text . '</a><br /><span class="desc-class">' . $item_desc . '</span></li>';
}
?>

<ul>
<?php print $output; ?>
</ul>
```

And here is the data format I suggest to use (separate all fields by `:`)

```
text1:text1-page-url:Text1 Description
text2:new-text2-page:Description For Text2
text3:different-page-text3:A Text3 Description
```